# How do you access data in a const char **& in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, reference

example code:

```
const char* list[] = {"Elem_E", "Elem_T", "Elem_R", "Turtle", "Rabbit"};
const char ** patterns=0;
.
.
.
bool sec_run = false;
patterns = list;
process_data(patterns, sec_run);
```

process_data function:

```
process_data(const char **& pattern, bool sec_run){
.
.
some_variable=0;
  for(int i; i < num_patterns;++i){
    if(!sec_run){
      some_variable = *pattern[i];
    }
    else{
      if(/* list element contains "_" */)continue;
      some_variable= /*letter after "_" */
    }
    if(some_variable  == 'E') multiplier = 0;
    else if(some_variable == 'T') multiplier = 1;
    else if(some_variable == 'R') multiplier = 2;
  }
}
```

So there is the base of what I'm trying to do. I cannot change signature for process_data.  To start i do not get how `some_variable = *pattern[i];` returns E,T, or R, and I cannot figure out how to iteratively access the full elements in the list. ie "Elem_E" to check for underscore and parse off the E.

I have little background in C++, but have used C numerous times. I am having a difficult time finding visual representation for char **& to help with based understanding of what is going on here, if you can point in the direction of a good tutorial with visual that will also suffice.

Sorry for confusion, forgot quotes in the list.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, reading a parameter passed by reference (with the `&`) works the same as reading a parameter passed by value (without the `&`). The difference happens when you assign to the parameter. If the parameter was passed by value then the assignment is only visible inside the function but if it was passed by reference the assignment will be visible outside.

```
int mynumber = 0;

void foo(int &x)
{
    printf("%d\n", x); //prints 0;
    x = 10;
}

int main()
{
    foo(mynumber);
    printf("%d\n", mynumber); // prints 10
}
```

The equivalent to this in plain C would be to make the `x` parameter into a pointer and add the required `*`s and `&`s:

```
int mynumber = 0;

void foo(int *x)
{
    printf("%d\n", *x);
    *x = 10;
}

int main()
{
    foo(&mynumber);
    printf("%d\n", mynumber); // prints 10
}
```

Coming back to your code, I don't really know how to solve all your problems (what does the constant `Elem_E` mean? Is your list NULL terminated or is there a length stored somewhere?) but what I can say is that as long as you don't want to change the `patterns` global variable from inside `process_data`, using a `char **&` will be the same as using a `char **`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how `some_variable` and `multiplier` will be used, but I made these changes to calculate them for each string in the list. The variable `sec_run` is not required in this approach. If no match is found, `some_variable` and `multiplier` are set to default values of '\0' and -1.

Output:

```
item=Elem_E some_variable=E multiplier=0
item=Elem_T some_variable=T multiplier=1
item=Elem_R some_variable=R multiplier=2
item=Turtle some_variable=  multiplier=-1
item=Rabbit some_variable=  multiplier=-1
```

Code:

```
void process_data(const char **& pattern, int num_patterns)
{
    const char * item;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_patterns; ++i)
    {
        item = pattern[i];
        if ( item == NULL ) continue;

        char some_variable = '\0';  // set to default for no match
        int multiplier = -1;    // set to default for no match
        int len = strlen(item);

        for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j)
        {
            if (item[j] == '_' && j + 1 < len)
                some_variable = item[j + 1];  /*letter after "_" */
        }
        if (some_variable == 'E') multiplier = 0;
        else if (some_variable == 'T') multiplier = 1;
        else if (some_variable == 'R') multiplier = 2;
        cout << "item=" << item << " some_variable=" << some_variable << " multiplier=" << multiplier << endl;
    }
}

void pattern_test()
{
    const char* list[] = { "Elem_E", "Elem_T", "Elem_R", "Turtle", "Rabbit" };
    const char ** patterns = list;
    // trick to calculate array length
    // length of entire array divided by length of one element
    int num_length = sizeof(list) / sizeof(list[0]);
    process_data(patterns, num_length);
}
```

Comment: I spent all day looking into things like strtok, find_first_of, etc looking for probably an over complicated way to do this.  I will have to check if this works.  The sec_run was for the function would be called twice, first to do things based off first character of each element, then second based off character after "_" if it had one. The actual code is compicated and a few hundred line.

Comment: And I get strtok won't work becuae it manipulates the original, at least i think it wont work, but i was not able to figure out strdup, or strcp for the individual elements in the list.

Comment: Yes, `strtok()` modifies the input string so it requires `char *` input - then the compiler would complain that you're passing `const char *` to `char *`. You could use a copy of the input though. `char * itemDup = strdup(pattern[i]);` creates a copy you can change. You have to call `free(itemDup);` after processing it, to free the heap memory that `strdup` allocated.  I was wondering about `sec_run` ... it may be possible to add your checks on the first character into the same loop as the checks on `"_"`.